# How to do URL rewriting

Tags: url-rewriting, apache2

I am very new to httpd server. And i have a immediate problem to solve. My server instance is running on centos box.

If a request comes to my server as

---

http://sub-domain.domain.com

---

This should be translated to

---

http://domain.com/key/sub-domain

---

I have configured many virtual host on my server. But this is quite a case and i am running out of ideas

Any suggestion: what should i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your using apache

```
ServerName sub-domain.domain.com
RedirectMatch /(.*) http://domain.com/key/sub-domain/$1
```

thus

```
http://sub-domain.domain.com/a-page-i-want-to-see.html
```

will send a 301 redirect to

```
http://domain.com/key/sub-domain/a-page-i-want-to-see.html
```

if you need to dynamically detect the sub-domain, you may need some additional settings.

[RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) is what you need, but I'm not sure about the specifics of how it works, you may need to use.

I did find the wildcard serverAlais for all the subdomains though.

```
ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias *.example.com

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ...
```

Comment: Hello Fire Crow,

actually i don't know well in advance about the value of "sub-domain". It will by system generated key.

Comment: Is there any way, I can test the sub-doamin thing on the localhost?

Comment: I have a local setup that includes bind as a local nameserver, if your on a *nix os you can put the subdomains in your /etc/hosts file

Comment: `RedirectMatch` does send a 302 on default.

Comment: Under Windows XP you can find here:

c:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Comment: I found some new info on dynamic domains, revised my answer.

Comment: Yes Sir; 

This dynamic domains are the thing i was looking for and well working poc is achieeved.

Thanks for your help Fire Crow.